# disable caching in IIS only for one particular app on the website

Tags: iis, caching, web-config

Is it possible to disable caching of aspx, ashx, and javascript files only on one particular app on the website, not for the website globally? Can it be done in the app's local web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following into web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
     </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does the **location path**  limit the instructions nested below to have effect only on the index.html file?

Comment: You can test it, because it works fine here, but it is not universal.